# Swagger datatype not generating docs

Tags: java, swagger, microservices, spark-java

I have the below code in Swagger,

```
@Path("/v1")
    @ApiOperation(value = "POST - Some Value", nickname = "post-funtion", consumes = "application/json", produces = "text/html; charset=UTF-8", tags = {
            "Some Controller" })
    @ApiImplicitParams({
            @ApiImplicitParam(name = "Authorization", paramType = "header", dataType = "string", format = "JWT", required = false, value = "A User Service JWT"),
            @ApiImplicitParam(name = "Request", value = "Request Object", paramType = "body", dataType = "org.pkg.SomeRequest", required = true) })
    @ApiResponses({
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Value Added", response = SomeResponse.class) })
private Object retrieveByName(Request request, Response response)
{
    return new RetrieveByNameRqstHandler(catalogService, request, response).handle();
}
```

The code is supposed to automatically generate default json request depending upon the datatype which in this case is `"org.pkg.SomeRequest"` but there is nothing generated. On the contrary if I change the "org.pkg.SomeRequest" with `"org.pkg.SomeResponse"` there is a default JSON generated for this. Can anybody help me please?

Consider both classes SomeRequest,SomeResponse have the same code.
This is the image where I use `"org.pkg.SomeRequest"` in the dataType
[image: This is the image where I use <code>"org.pkg.SomeRequest"</code> in the dataType]
[image: This is the image where I use <code>"org.pkg.SomeResponse"</code> in the dataType]

This is the image where I use `"org.pkg.SomeResponse"` in the dataType

Comment: Can you give us more information about the method that are you applying this Swagger annotations?

Comment: Just updated...should i give u the code also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/1559#issuecomment-261943276) on Swagger core project, if you add the annotation `@ApiImplicitParam` should resolve your problem.

```
@ApiImplicitParams({
    @ApiImplicitParam(
        required = true,
        dataType = "com.example.SomeObjectDto",
        paramType = "body"
    )
})
```

But normally if you just add the class on your method signature it'll work.

```
private Object retrieveByName(SomeObjectDto someObjectDto) {
    someCode();
}
```

Also SomeObjectDto class should contain "get" methods for your variables like.

```
class SomeObjectDto {
    private String info;

    getInfo(){
        return info;
    }
}
```

Will produce the following JSon.

> { info: "string" }

Comment: As per the Java Spark Architecture you have to use Request, Response as the parameters. Is there an alternative to this...One more thing why is SystemResponse working fine but SystemRequest giving issues...

Comment: Which version of Swagger you're using? Did you check this link? Also, if SomeRequest and SomeResponde are identical both should work, are you able to provide those classes source code?

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/1559#issuecomment-261943276

Comment: The problem is in the actual project SomeRequest and SomeResponse are different. I cannot update the actual code so have created a mock of the actual code...When I use a class which is already referred in the Swapper Docs Annotations  somewhere it works fine ex. in SomeResponse datatype case, there is SomeResponse.class already present as `response = SomeResponse.class` but when I use SomeRequest it cannot convert it into JSON maybe becasue it not referred anywhere in the Swagger Annotations, I'm not sure...

Comment: My version is 1.5

Comment: As this issue on GitHub, if you insert the dataType on @ApiImplicitParam it should work. I'll update my answer. https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/1559#issuecomment-261943276

Comment: That's what I'm doing I gues...Can u please tell me what I have to do differently....

Comment: On your question you said that SomeRequest and SomeReponse have the same code but on your comment you told that they're different. Just confirming, both classes have public constructor, getters and setters? If you get swagger.json, did it return something for SomeRequest?

Comment: Yes the class has default constructor with all getters/setters

Comment: If you try to get swagger.json, did it return something for SomeRequest? Or onlt for SomeResponse?

Answer (score 1):

`ApiImplicitParam` can map a parameter to a correct type, but the type must be detected by swagger, so must be a valid reference.
The only way I could make this working is by using `additionalModels` method.

Example in spring-boot:
configure swagger

```
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import com.fasterxml.classmate.TypeResolver;
...

@Bean
public Docket api(TypeResolver typeResolver) {
  return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
    .groupName("your-group-rest-api")
    .select()
    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("your.package"))
    .paths(PathSelectors.any())
    .build()
    .additionalModels(typeResolver.resolve(YourModel.class))
    .apiInfo(apiInfo());
}
```

controller

```
@ApiOperation...
@ApiImplicitParams(
  @ApiImplicitParam(dataType = "YourModel", name = "requestJson", paramType = "body"))
@ApiResponses...
@RequestMapping...
public void yourMethod(@RequestBody String requestJson,...)
```

Of course, you could have an InputStream parameter for the request and map that to your model.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with `ApiImplicitParam`, and after 2 hours of app rebuilding I found out one more solution))

It doesn't look very logical, but it works:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Запрос...", response = Request.class)
    @ApiImplicitParams({
       @ApiImplicitParam(name = "request", value = "DTO Запрос...", required = true, 
    dataType = "Request", dataTypeClass = Request.class, paramType = "body")
    })
    @ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Успешный запрос", response = Response.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Ошибка в запросе"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Внутренняя ошибка сервера")
    })
    public Response processRequest(@ApiParam(hidden = true)
    @RequestBody Object request) {
            return service.processRequest(request);
    }
```

The key is to set the class of your request DTO in `@ApiOperation` response field, and at the same time to set `@ApiResponses` group of annotations.

It seems it helps swagger to detect the type of request correctly.
And response is being displayed correctly by swagger as well:

[image]

But of course when I found the solution posted by @danidacila I've used it in my app, because it looks much more preferrable and smart and it works as well.